# Read details of an AWS ec2 instance using lambda with boto python API resulted in 'EC2' object has no attribute 'Instance'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

My goal is to read details of an AWS ec2 instance using lambda with boto python API. Specifically, I would like to read out the attribute launch_time of the ec2 instance.

**When execute, I receive the following error:**

```
'EC2' object has no attribute 'Instance': AttributeError
```

**Example:**

Python code:

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

instance = ec2.Instance('id')
launch_time = instance.launch_time
```

Policy:

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "ec2:Instance"
   ],
   "Resource": [
     "arn:aws:ec2:${var.region}:${var.account}:instance/*"
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#instance

have to initialize ressource instead of client.

**resource**

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
```

**instead of client**

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
```

**additional check the policy**

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "ec2:DescribeInstances"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "*"
  ]
}
```

DescribeInstances instead of Instances. And wildcard ressource, arn specific ist not supported for DescribeInstances.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-ec2-console.html#ex-read-only

> The Amazon EC2 ec2:Describe* API actions do not support resource-level
>   permissions, so you cannot control which individual resources users
>   can view in the console. Therefore, the * wildcard is necessary in the
>   Resource element of the above statement. For more information about
>   which ARNs you can use with which Amazon EC2 API actions, see
>   Supported Resource-Level Permissions for Amazon EC2 API Actions.